# Is there any Event in Microsoft Graph API when new email arrived in Office365 email

Tags: c#, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I have been working with Microsoft Graph API [Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/mail_api_overview). i am wondering that if there is any event/process through I can read only new email when arrived. I can list last 10 emails only and I have to process last 10 emails every time. i just wanted to process new email like logic app does.

I could not able to find any method or event to get this done?

Comment: have you found any solution for this ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I could not find any until was working on it.

Answer (score 0):

try looking into [Creating webhook subscriptions](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/subscription_post_subscriptions) so that you get notified on changes of your mailbox.